# Need later Samsung-specific posts to get a photo from dropbox to Gallery

Tags: photos, downloading, gallery, dropbox

Can't believe how hard this is and the lack of recent posts with current menu options.  I have a photo modified on the PC, saved in dropbox and cannot set it as my wallpaper on my Samsung S8.  Every help post found shows options not on current apps.  Dropbox has very limited options, hold and press doesn't help, and select and download icons produce blank screens.

Answer (score 0):

The current Dropbox does not "have limited options". It just may not be able to place exactly where you want, because of privilege concerns. I'll demonstrate how to get a photo to the "Downloads" folder, for example, where it can probably be able to be incorporated from whatever your wallpaper app is.

1. Start Dropbox and find the file within its folder hierarchy.
2. From its upper "hamburger" menu, which is short to start, scroll to "Export".
3. Choose the first option "Save to device".
4. In the upper left menu, it will have probably given "Documents" as a target.
5. From its down arrow dropdown, select your device name.
6. Scroll the device folders available to find your "Download" folder, select it.
7. Drill further or more if you like, finally, hit the "Save" button.